# Exim not Listening on port 465 or 587 for TLS connection

Tags: smtp, ubuntu-14.04, exim, ufw, smtp-auth

I am configuring Exim on a Ubuntu server to send and receive mails via **TLS.**

Followed many guides which shows on how to configure Exim with TLS but still my Exim doesn't listen on 465 or 587

Exim only listen's on port 25 and I am able to send an receive mails

This is the official guide that I followed:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Exim4

But still no luck, also I cannot find any reference in the config files which indicates on which ports is exim listening

I have also allowed the ports 465 and 587 via ufw using the command:

```
ufw allow 465
ufw allow 465
```

but still Exim won't listen on 465 or 587, can anybody help me on why this is happening or is there are steps that I am missing

Comment: Run `ss -nl | egrep "25|465|587"` to ensure you listen these ports.

Comment: @Kondybas only shows 25 .... what should I do to make them listen?

Comment: Run `exim -bP | grep "daemon_smtp_ports"` to ensure you have SMA/SMTPS ports enabled.

Comment: @Kondybas thanks for the reply..... it shows the following output: **daemon_smtp_ports = smtp**  .. i tried to add the following line **daemon_smtp_ports = 25 : 587** in `/etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf` but it deosn't load it

Comment: Read soroughly the guide. You can miss some significant step(s).

Comment: @Kondybas tried them all like this one here: [link](https://debian-administration.org/users/lee/weblog/19) but still no sucess

Comment: At start exim logs the addresses and ports it's listening to. If that won't help `exim4 -d -bd` would start with the same info in more detail.

Comment: Also, try disabling `ufw` and then seeing.

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu 18.04 I've found that the following works in `update-exim4.conf.conf`:

```
dc_local_interfaces='<; [0.0.0.0]:465; [0.0.0.0]:587'
```

Then the usual: run `update-exim4.conf` and restart the service.

Check (sorry - there are more modern ways, but fingers remember `netstat`):

```
# netstat --listen -lnp | grep exim
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:465             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10874/exim4         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:587             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10874/exim4
```

NB: It may be good idea to enable port 25 as well. For example, some local services may want to send mail to localhost:25.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure it in the "/etc/default/exim4" file. There it says:

```
# Options for the SMTP listener daemon. By default, it is listening on
# port 25 only. To listen on more ports, it is recommended to use
# -oX 25:587:10025 -oP /run/exim4/exim.pid 
SMTPLISTENEROPTIONS=''
```

So to make it listen on additional ports you have to change SMTPLISTENEROPTIONS in /etc/default/exim4. To use only port 587 you have to write this:

```
SMTPLISTENEROPTIONS='-oX 25:587:10025 -oP /run/exim4/exim.pid'
```

And to also use port 465 you have to write this:

```
SMTPLISTENEROPTIONS='-oX 25:465:587:10025 -oP /run/exim4/exim.pid'
```

Afterward you have to restart exim:

```
/etc/init.d/exim4 restart
```

When using port 465 you also have to add

```
tls_on_connect_ports = 465
```

to your exim configuration file so that the SSL session is immediately started when connecting to port 465.

Afterward you can check the connection:

*Without SSL:*

```
telnet localhost 25
EHLO test
```

*With SSL:*

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:25 -starttls smtp
EHLO test
```

```
openssl s_client -crlf -connect localhost:465
EHLO test
```

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:587 -starttls smtp
EHLO test
```

If your exim server manages multiple domains and you are using a different certificate for each domain, you can use the "-servername" parameter when testing your server:

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:587 -servername example.com -starttls smtp
EHLO test
```

Then you can check if the correct certificate was sent.